# HBase - SAS Integration and Read

Tags: hadoop, sas, hbase, cloudera

I have cloudera cluster(kerberos enabled) and HBase is running in it. I need few tables in HBase with the filter condition which needs to read/write from external SAS server.

I am trying to achieve this through Thrift and Python whereas I have installed python in my SAS Server and accessing HBase through Thrift. I have some limitations in Filter Conditions like SingleColumnValueFilter and other options are not supported with Thrift Python. HappyBase also we tried and there are some limitations and not a stable one to use.

Do we have any other possiblities to do this?

Can anyone please help me out on this.

Thanks..